# Understaing the "fillable" in Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel

Using models is one the best facts in Laravel, but when using a model, it is not like my "native" environment (J2EE, models declare all DB table colums), it has three variable, and which of them is "fillable". When seeing the tutorials online, the fillable hold some specific data like in a table :

```
Table : Users
Fields : Name, Email, Id, Password
```

They put `protected $fillable = ['nom', 'email', 'password'];` which means we've got rid of the id .. But the word fillable means something we can fill and it makes sense hince the ID is auto-incremented, but let's say I want to execute some update to JUST the name field, will that return an error cause the fillable instruction contain 2 additional fields ? As in their documentation :

```
 You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. 
The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. 
However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable or 
guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against 
mass-assignment.


  A mass-assignment vulnerability occurs when a user passes an unexpected
 HTTP parameter through a request, and that parameter changes a column in 
your database you did not expect. For example, a malicious user might send 
an is_admin parameter through an HTTP request, which is then mapped onto
 your model's create method, allowing the user to escalate themselves to an
 administrator.
```

From which I resume : If a single input is sent in a HTTP request WITHOUT other inputs (mass), it will stopped ? Or that the user have to enter each of them in inputs to get them inserted ? In that case what happens if a value isn't set (null) ? It will be considered as not filled ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Say we want to protect the role field from being mass-assignment, so, there are two ways to do this in the User model. We can either specify a `$guarded` property to specify a list of fields that we want to exclude from mass-assignment, or we can specify a `$fillable` property to specify a list of fields that we want to allow for mass-assignment